# all gradestate.dat seqno: -1 why?

Tags: mariadb, galera, mysql-cluster

All my 3 nodes in mariadb galera cluster seqno is -1 and when i restart the whole cluster i need to start with --wsrep_new_cluster just to start the other nodes. can anyone help me with this?

all 3 nodes grastate.dat is like this

```
# GALERA saved state
version: 2.1
uuid:    b4ab9e1d-b247-11e8-b680-322574505349
seqno:   -1
safe_to_bootstrap: 0
```

but it state that the node is totally synced

```
2018-09-10 11:46:26 0 [Note] WSREP: save pc into disk
2018-09-10 11:46:26 0 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 1, memb_num = 3
2018-09-10 11:46:26 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: Waiting for state UUID.
2018-09-10 11:46:27 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 188285b2-b4ac-11e8-9e10-434cd7119506
2018-09-10 11:46:27 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 188285b2-b4ac-11e8-9e10-434cd7119506 from 0 (GALERANODE2)
2018-09-10 11:46:27 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 188285b2-b4ac-11e8-9e10-434cd7119506 from 1 (GALERANODE3)
2018-09-10 11:46:27 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 188285b2-b4ac-11e8-9e10-434cd7119506 from 2 (GALERANODE1)
2018-09-10 11:46:27 0 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
        version    = 4,
        component  = PRIMARY,
        conf_id    = 10,
        members    = 3/3 (joined/total),
        act_id     = 6374,
        last_appl. = 0,
        protocols  = 0/8/3 (gcs/repl/appl),
        group UUID = b4ab9e1d-b247-11e8-b680-322574505349
2018-09-10 11:46:27 0 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [28, 28]
2018-09-10 11:46:27 0 [Note] WSREP: Trying to continue unpaused monitor
2018-09-10 11:46:27 1 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: b4ab9e1d-b247-11e8-b680-322574505349:6374, view# 11: Primary, number of nodes: 3, my index: 1, protocol version 3
2018-09-10 11:46:27 1 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2018-09-10 11:46:27 1 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 8 (3, 2)
2018-09-10 11:46:27 1 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 6374, protocol version: 3
2018-09-10 11:46:27 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2018-09-10 11:46:27 0 [Note] WSREP: Member 0.0 (GALERANODE2) synced with group.
2018-09-10 11:46:29 0 [Note] WSREP: (2efef35d, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning    message relay requesting off
```

here is the mysql status in mariadb

```
MariaDB [(none)]>  show global status like 'wsrep_%';
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                                                           |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_apply_oooe             | 0.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_apply_oool             | 0.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_apply_window           | 1.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_causal_reads           | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance     | 1.627988                                                    |
| wsrep_cert_index_size        | 2771                                                        |
| wsrep_cert_interval          | 0.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id        | 11                                                          |
| wsrep_cluster_size           | 3                                                           |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid     | b4ab9e1d-b247-11e8-b680-322574505349                        |
| wsrep_cluster_status         | Primary                                                     |
| wsrep_commit_oooe            | 0.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_commit_oool            | 0.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_commit_window          | 1.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_connected              | ON                                                          |
| wsrep_desync_count           | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_evs_delayed            |                                                             |
| wsrep_evs_evict_list         |                                                             |
| wsrep_evs_repl_latency       | 0/0/0/0/0                                                   |
| wsrep_evs_state              | OPERATIONAL                                                 |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused    | 0.000039                                                    |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns | 9680789338                                                  |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv      | 74                                                          |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent      | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid             | 2efef35d-b269-11e8-a093-322d1564170c                        |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses     | 192.168.12.106:3306,192.168.12.107:3306,192.168.12.105:3306 |
| wsrep_last_committed         | 6374                                                        |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts        | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto    | 6142                                                        |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures    | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_commits          | 2025                                                        |
| wsrep_local_index            | 1                                                           |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue       | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg   | 0.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_max   | 1                                                           |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_min   | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_replays          | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_send_queue       | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg   | 0.000177                                                    |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_max   | 2                                                           |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_min   | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_state            | 4                                                           |
| wsrep_local_state_comment    | Synced                                                      |
| wsrep_local_state_uuid       | b4ab9e1d-b247-11e8-b680-322574505349                        |
| wsrep_protocol_version       | 8                                                           |
| wsrep_provider_name          | Galera                                                      |
| wsrep_provider_vendor        | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                           |
| wsrep_provider_version       | 25.3.23(r3789)                                              |
| wsrep_ready                  | ON                                                          |
| wsrep_received               | 1929                                                        |
| wsrep_received_bytes         | 17781                                                       |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes        | 3170573338                                                  |
| wsrep_repl_keys              | 14449216                                                    |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes        | 115698328                                                   |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes       | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_replicated             | 3722                                                        |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes       | 3286522736                                                  |
| wsrep_thread_count           | 2                                                               |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
58 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

gradestate.dat contains seqno: -1 while it is running so that if it crashes for any reason it contains an state that says it needs a SST on restart.

Upon a safe shutdown this file will be populated with the last seqno processed.

A `wsrep_new_cluster` is only needed on the most up to date node (not all) upon restart. Other cluster nodes will use this as a SST donor.